# Import some code so that loop become infinite?

Tags: java

make loop infinite .add some line

```
public class Puzzel4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Place your declaration for i here
        while (i != 0) {
            i >>>= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: International day of puzzles.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this is not a puzzle site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
byte i=-1;
```

From comments:

> Unsigned right-shifting, in Java, causes unary promotion to `int`: the
>   byte `0xff` becomes the `int` `0xffffffff`, which is then right-shifted to
>   `0x7fffffff` and narrowed to `0xff` for storage.

Comment: Explanation is more than welcomed here.

Comment: Unsigned right-shifting, in Java, causes unary promotion to int: the byte `0xff` becomes the int `0xffffffff`, which is then right-shifted to `0x7fffffff` and narrowed to `0xff` for storage.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19 there is an explanation of using the unsigned right shift operators on negative values.